# Network Programming Issue - buffer will only send once to the server

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, buffer

I am trying to send a file to a server using socket programming. My server and client are able to connect to each other successfully however I am expecting the while loop below to go through the entire file and add it to the server. The issue I am having is that it only send the first chunk and not the rest.

On the client side I have the following:

```
memset(szbuffer, 0, sizeof(szbuffer)); //Initialize the buffer to zero
    int file_block_size;

    while ((file_block_size = fread(szbuffer, sizeof(char), 256, file)) > 0){

        if (send(s, szbuffer, file_block_size, 0) < 0){
            throw "Error: failed to send file";
            exit(1);
        } //Loop while there is still contents in the file

        memset(szbuffer, 0, sizeof(szbuffer)); //Reset the buffer to zero
    }
```

On the server side I have the following:

```
while (1)

    {

        FD_SET(s, &readfds);  //always check the listener

        if (!(outfds = select(infds, &readfds, NULL, NULL, tp))) {}

        else if (outfds == SOCKET_ERROR) throw "failure in Select";

        else if (FD_ISSET(s, &readfds))  cout << "got a connection request" << endl;

        //Found a connection request, try to accept. 

        if ((s1 = accept(s, &ca.generic, &calen)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
            throw "Couldn't accept connection\n";

        //Connection request accepted.
        cout << "accepted connection from " << inet_ntoa(ca.ca_in.sin_addr) << ":"
            << hex << htons(ca.ca_in.sin_port) << endl;

        //Fill in szbuffer from accepted request.
        while (szbuffer > 0){
            if ((ibytesrecv = recv(s1, szbuffer, 256, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                throw "Receive error in server program\n";

            //Print reciept of successful message. 
            cout << "This is the message from client: " << szbuffer << endl;

            File.open("test.txt", ofstream::out | ofstream::app);
            File << szbuffer;
            File.close();

            //Send to Client the received message (echo it back).
            ibufferlen = strlen(szbuffer);

            if ((ibytessent = send(s1, szbuffer, ibufferlen, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                throw "error in send in server program\n";
            else cout << "Echo message:" << szbuffer << endl;
        }

    }//wait loop

} //try loop
```

The code above is the setup for the connection between the client and server which works great. It is in a constant while loop waiting to receive new requests. The issue is with my buffer. Once I send the first buffer over, the next one doesn't seem to go through. Does anyone know what I can do to set the server to receive more than just one buffer? I've tried a while loop but did not get any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code that sends the file from the server appears to send consecutive sections of the file correctly.

Your code that appears to have the intention of receiving the file from the client performs the following steps:

1) Wait for and accept a socket.

2) Read up to 256 bytes from the socket.

3) Write those bytes back to the socket.

At this point the code appears to go back to waiting for another connection, and keeping the original connection open, and, at least based on the code you posted, obviously leaking the file descriptor.

So, the issues seems to be that the client and the server disagreeing on what should happen. The client tries to send the entire file, and doesn't read from the socket. The server reads the first 256 bytes from the socket, and writes it back to the client.

Of course, its entirely possible that portions of the code not shown implement some of the missing pieces, but there's definitely a disconnect here between what the sending side is doing, and what the receiving side is doing.

Answer (score 0):

> buffer will only send once to the server

No, your server is only reading once from the client. You have to loop, just like the sending loop does.

Comment: Where would I need to have this loop? As mentioned above the recv() will loop infinitely. I've tried to make a while loop that would go until the buffer is zero however this ended up in an infinite loop. I've added send(s, szbuffer, 0, 0); in the client so it can tell the server that it is 0. Wouldn't this be sufficient to break out of the loop? @EJP

Comment: @VinceAbruzzese: `send(s, szbuffer, 0, 0);` will send zero bytes to the server, in other words, send nothing, so it won't be telling the server anything at all when you do that.

Comment: So if I were to do a while loop of something like this while (sizeof(szbuffer) > 0) { it wouldn't break the loop if a buffer of size zero is sent over? @PaulGriffiths

Comment: No, because "sending over a buffer of size zero" makes no sense - there'd be nothing to send. "Sending over a buffer of size zero" is the same thing as saying "not sending anything". Remember, the server has no idea if client is making a thousand calls to `send()` with one character at a time, or one call to `send()` with a thousand characters at once.

Comment: @VinceAbruzzese What `recv()` loop? You have an infinite *`select()/accept()`* loop, and one `recv()` per accept. NB `send(s, szbuffer, 0, 0)` will do precisely nothing.

Comment: The issue here, which was pointed out by Paul and Sam is that the select()/accept() above will only give me the first buffer because once the loop is complete it will wait for another connection. I am trying to get it to loop inside that loop to send all the contents of the file before returning to the top of the loop to wait for another connection. This is what I am referring to as the recv() loop @EJP

Comment: @VinceAbruzzese: The easiest solution here is to have your client calculate the size of the file, and send that to the server, followed by a newline, followed by the actual file. The server reads the size, ignores the newline, and then loops until its received the number of characters specified by the size of the file. Once it has, then continue with your loop. As I said, somehow the client has to communicate to the server when it's done.

Comment: @VinceAbruzzo I am commenting on the code you posted. If you want me to comment on your recv() loop, post a recv() loop.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths how would I be able to implement that? Doesn't the send function require that I send a char. If I am sending the size of the file ill need to send it as an int, correct?

Comment: @VinceAbruzzese: You could use `write()`, or just `sprintf()` it to a string.

Comment: @EJP I have added this while loop to show what I was trying but it does not seem like a good solution as mentioned before that a buffer of size zero does not send anything